# Outlook missing "Publish to GAL"

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365, public-key-encryption

Unable to encrypt emails with valid certificates in exchange environment.

I just thought of publishing the public keys to GAL but **Publish to GAL** option is missing

[image: Publish to GAL missing]

Things i've tried :

1. Re-download Address book
2. Delete auto-complete entry
3. Update Outlook client

I don't want to create a new profile or start over as that would be followed by downloading few gigs of emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another email account configured in my Outlook

Weirdly enough, Removing the other account brought **Publish To GAL** back & I can encrypt emails again **:)**